# I can't log in Xorg in ubuntu 18.04 and I can log in Wayland

Tags: 18.04, xorg, login

If I log in, There's just gray display and I can move the mouse pointer. (I downloaded the pop theme, so It's not purple but gray.) But if I log in Wayland, I can log in.

And It's A Xorg log file. (/var/log/Xorg.1.log)

```
... SKIP ...
[    52.409] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
[    52.424] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    52.424] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[    52.444] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    52.444] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[    52.475] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[    52.475] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[    52.475] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[    52.476] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

How can I fix? And I should use Wayland?

EDIT: I solved, and I can log in Xorg but I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: What did you try in fixing this issue?